# Solving $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt n\int_0^{\frac12}(1-3x^2+x^4)^n\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt n\int_0^{\frac12}(1-3x^2+x^4)^n\:\mathrm{d}x=0.5116...$$
Attempting the limit above. I'm only average in calculus, and none of the usual methods seem to work.

I did find these equivalent forms of $1-3x^2+x^4$ that are useless to me but may give you some ideas:

- $(x+\varphi)(x-\varphi)(x+\varphi-1)(x-\varphi+1)$, where $\varphi=\frac{1+\sqrt5}2$
- $(x^2-\varphi^2)(x^2-(\varphi-1)^2)$
- $(x^2+(2\varphi-1)x+1)(x^2-(2\varphi-1)x+1)$
- $(x^2-x-1)(x^2+x-1)$
- $(x^2-1)^2-x^2$
- $\left(x^2-\frac32\right)^2-\frac54$
- If the polynomial's domain is restricted to $[0,\varphi-1]$, its inverse is $\sqrt{\frac32-\sqrt{x+\frac54}}.$

I've found these two infinite series that should be equivalent to the limit by "solving" the integral. The first series is derived from expanding $\left(\left(x^2-\frac32\right)^2-\frac54\right)^n$ with the binomial theorem:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt n\left(-\frac54\right)^n\sum_{m=0}^n\binom nm\left(-\frac95\right)^m\sum_{k=0}^{2m}\frac1{2k+1}\binom{2m}k\left(-\frac16\right)^k$$

[Wolfram Alpha evaluated the indefinite integral as an infinite series](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Integrate%5B%281-3x%5E2%2Bx%5E4%29%5En%2Cx%5D), so calculating the integral itself is likely a bad idea. Attached to its answer was a unit complex correction term of some sort that should be $1$ when $0\le x\le\frac12$. The second series simplifies the output from Wolfram Alpha, where $x^{\bar n}=x(x+1)\cdots(x+n-1)$ is the rising factorial:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{n}\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{\varphi^{2\left(i-j\right)}}{\left(2i+2j+1\right)4^{i+j}}\frac{(-n)^{\bar i}}{i!}\frac{(-n)^{\bar{j}}}{j!}$$

The only context I have for this problem was that I received it from someone else who sent it after getting stuck, who had received it from someone else who sent it after getting stuck. How should this integral be solved?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the substitution $\sqrt{n}x = s$:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^{\frac{\sqrt{n}}{2}}\left(1-\frac{3s^2}{n}+\frac{s^4}{n^2}\right)^nds \longrightarrow \int_0^\infty e^{-3s^2}ds = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{12}} \approx 0.51166_\cdots$$

by dominated convergence.

Comment: as always, To the point and Brilliant

Comment: @DheerajGujrathi thank you for the kind words!